# context object returned in getContext() method of MicrosoftTeams SDK has subEntityId as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, microsoft-teams

I have created deeplink by using `microsoftTeams.shareDeeplink()` method which takes `subEntityId`,`subEntityLabel`,`subEntityWebUrl` as parameters.

I tried to consume the deeplink created. A[ccording to the documentation provided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/deeplinks), `subEntityId`  can be retrieved back in the context when the link is followed and tab is reloaded by using `microsoftTeams.getContext()`. However the context object retrieved has `subEntityId:undefined`.

Even though the `subEntityId` has been provided while calling `shareDeeplink()`, context object does not contain `subEntityId` when deeplink followed.

Can somebody please help me on this.

url:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/385875ca-c900-4f42-9ba8-5bd45fa35bb9/aa13ec1b-376a-11e5-6767-2c337afbce1e?webUrl=https%3a%2f%2fwidget.parrot365.com&label=ui+workspace+1&context=%7b%0d%0a++%22canvasUrl%22%3a+%22https%3a%2f%2fp365.wittyparrot.com%3a3000%23%2fmain%3fsource%3dteams%26workspaceId%3daa13ec1b-376a-11e5-6767-2c337afbce1e%22%2c%0d%0a++%22channelId%22%3a+%2219%3a257ce3c0795a4477bb404d2c3db2b5a4%40thread.skype%22%0d%0a%7d&tenantId=fce50195-2315-47af-a684-ff91de5f9075`

JSON object:

```json
{  
   "channelId":"19:257ce3c0795a4477bb404d2c3db2b5a4@thread.skype",
   "entityId":"aa13ec1b-376a-11e5-6767-2c337afbce1e",
   "groupId":"ed9fa599-ca43-41c5-b500-6a09a2688a25",
   "isFullScreen":false,
   "locale":"en-in",
   "subEntityId":undefined,
   "teamId":"19:257ce3c0795a4477bb404d2c3db2b5a4@thread.skype",
   "theme":"default",
   "tid":"fce50195-2315-47af-a684-ff91de5f9075",
   "upn":"sudheer@wittyparrot.com"
}
```

Note: On calling `shareDeeplink(subEntityId,subEntityLabel)`, [according to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/deeplinks) it should display dialog box containing a link with label as `subEntityLabel`. However it is displaying the link with label as `entityLabel`.

Comment: Could you add the URL you generated and the context you received (as JSON) to your question?

Comment: Hi Marc I have added url and the context object, also please go through the note i have provided in the question.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Can you also add the JS you're using to create the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention calling `shareDeeplink(subEntityId,subEntityLabel)` but the right format is to use a JSON object as the parameter: `shareDeepLink({subEntityId: subEntityId, subEntityLabel: subEntityLabel} )`